# Calling appropriate method for vector of derived classes

Tags: c++, stdvector, unique-ptr, stdmap

I have a map of key and std::vector and following code.

```
std::map<Key, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> myMap;

class Foo
{
    // removed for brevity
};

class Boo : public Foo
{
    // removed for brevity
};

class Doo : public Foo
{
    // removed for brevity
};

void doSomething(std::vector<std:unique_ptr<Boo>>& booList)
{
    // removed for brevity
}

void doSomething(std::vector<std:unique_ptr<Doo>>& dooList)
{
    // removed for brevity
}
```

And iterating as following;

```
for(auto& item : myMap)
{
    // removed for brevity
    doSomething(it.second);
}
```

So while iterating on the map, I want to call appropriate function for each element of map based on its derived class type but received the following error.

```
non-const lvalue reference to type 'vector<unique_ptr<Boo, default_delete<Boo>>, allocator<unique_ptr<Boo, default_delete<Boo>>>>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'vector<unique_ptr<Foo, default_delete<Foo>>, allocator<unique_ptr<Foo, default_delete<Foo>>>>'
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this without any casting?

Comment: `unique_ptr` requires exclusive ownership. Your range iteration is by value, which means that your range iteration makes a copy of every map element. The entire vector. Even if `unique_ptr` wasn't an issue, making a copy of each entire vector in the map is horribly inefficient. You need to iterate by reference. If you want to iterate by value, at the very least you need to use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Are you sure you got the code example right? `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Boo>>` is the value type of the map and `doSomething` takes a `std::vector<std:unique_ptr<Boo>>&`. No mention of `Foo` anywhere but in the error message.

Comment: @cadaniluk I'm fixing now, thanks! To make it clear I modified code a bit.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I receive the same error if I change it to reference as well like `for(auto& item : myMap)`

Comment: Now, how do imagine this to work conceptually? A `Foo` can only have so much information and a `Boo` *extends* that information. `doSomething` on a `Boo` might require that additional information, but a `Foo` does not contain it. You could do downcasting with `dynamic_cast`. You don't want to, but is probably the only way to tell the compiler "yes, I am absolutely sure that this `Foo` is actually a `Boo` and thus will work."

Comment: but the Foo pointer points to a Boo object? And yeah I dont want to do a type casting as the number of derived classes increases, it will also make the code more unreadable

Comment: Right, but the compiler cannot know that. `dynamic_cast` is exactly for those cases, where you are 100% sure that downcasting works. if you are not deadsure and don't want to cast (which is honorable and good), rethink your approach.

Comment: @cadaniluk, I guess another way is, making a virtual function in the base object and overriding it in derived ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think theres a way to do it without casting if the functions aren't member functions of the class. Otherwise there would be no way to know what `Foo` could be downcast as. You could do something like this to call through on the pointers to `Foo`.

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
    virtual void doSomething(std::vector<std:unique_ptr<T>>& FooList);
};

class Boo : public Foo<Boo>
{
    virtual void doSomething(std::vector<std:unique_ptr<Boo>>& BooList) override;
};

class Doo : public Foo<Doo>
{
    virtual void doSomething(std::vector<std:unique_ptr<Doo>>& DooList) override;
};
```

Comment: what is the point of giving Doo as a template parameter in this line ? `class Doo : public Foo<Doo>`

Comment: it lets you override the `doSomething` method in `Foo`with a different function parameter.

Comment: I already override doSomething() in derived class as a member function with respective parameter. So this seems a bit redundant. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would write:

```
void callByFoo(Foo* foo) {
}

int main() {
    Boo* bp = new Boo();
    callByFoo(bp);
}
```

But with smart ptr you are initializing references, so you have references to different types, so this does not work:

```
void callByFoo(std::unique_ptr<Foo>& fooRef) {
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Boo> bp = std::make_unique<Boo>();
    callByFoo(bp);
}
```

I assume comparing with first example it is as you would write:

```
void callByFoo(Foo*& fooRef) {
}

int main() {
    Boo* bp = new Boo();
    callByFoo(bp);
}
```

So to make it work use base pointer and types will match, like in this example:

```
void callByFoo(std::unique_ptr<Foo>& fooRef) {
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> bp = std::make_unique<Boo>();
    callByFoo(bp);
}
```

In your example you will obviously have to also change methods to be virtual and function signature would look like this:

```
void doSomething(std::vector<std:unique_ptr<Foo>>& booList)
{
    // removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: Yes, and applied your solution.

Comment: This is not a solution! This is explanation why it is not compiling with other example.

Comment: If this is not a solution why are you posting this as a solution then? You should post a comment to the question then.

Comment: I thought this is self explanatory, but if its not I updated the answer.

Comment: It was not, thanks! But the issue is I want to call the method with derived class as parameter type not base class

Comment: "In your example you will obviously have to also change methods to be virtual"

Comment: I didn't see this on your updated answer before, but anyway as I mentioned on other answer, by the design of the app I can't proceed with that way.

Comment: So  explain what it means the "design of my app", are those the functions that are overloaded and taking different objects?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a virtual method, and iterate on each elements of the vector.

Example below in C++14 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
  public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class Boo : public Foo
{
  public:
    virtual void doSomething() override
    {
        cout << "Boo do something" << endl;
    }
};

class Doo : public Foo
{
  public:
    virtual void doSomething() override
    {
        cout << "Doo do something" << endl;
    }
};

using Key = int;
map<Key, vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>> myMap;

int main()
{
    myMap[10].push_back(make_unique<Boo>());
    myMap[10].push_back(make_unique<Doo>());

    myMap[1000].push_back(make_unique<Doo>());
    myMap[1000].push_back(make_unique<Boo>());

    for (auto& kv: myMap) {
        cout << "key: " << kv.first << endl;
        for (auto& foo: kv.second) {
            foo->doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is one alternative but design of the app doesn't allow me to apply this.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify the implementation of Foo, Boo, Doo, then you can define non member overloaded functions, but which not take a vector as argument but an element of vector, because you cannot pass a vector<B*> to a function expecting a vector<A*> even if B is a derived class of A. Then hoping that Foo is polymorphic, you can choose the right function by dynamic_cast.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    virtual void dummy_function_used_to_have_polymorphism() {}
};

class Boo : public Foo
{
};

class Doo : public Foo
{
};

void doSomething(Boo& boo)
{
    cout << "Boo do something" << endl;
}

void doSomething(Doo& doo)
{
    cout << "Doo do something" << endl;
}

using Key = int;
map<Key, vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>> myMap;

int main()
{
    myMap[10].push_back(make_unique<Boo>());
    myMap[10].push_back(make_unique<Doo>());

    myMap[1000].push_back(make_unique<Doo>());
    myMap[1000].push_back(make_unique<Boo>());

    for (auto& kv: myMap) {
        cout << "key: " << kv.first << endl;
        for (auto& foo: kv.second) {
            if (auto p = dynamic_cast<Boo*>(foo.get())) {
                doSomething(*p);
            } else
            if (auto p = dynamic_cast<Doo*>(foo.get())) {
                doSomething(*p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```